# Master Card is giving AVS error for Test mode in Production account: Authorize.net

Tags: android, authorize.net

I am using master card to make payment on authorize.net.
It is giving transaction successful on authorize.net sandbox but gives an AVS error (AVS is not applicable for this transaction) for test mode in Production account.
16 digit visa card is working well on both sandbox and production account.
Do any one have idea about this?

Comment: You didn't really post an **actual** card number with the expiration data and CCV number on a **PUBLIC** web site, right?  As far as the error, talk to the support folks at authorize.net.

Answer (score 0):

AVS is not actually performed in the sandbox and always returns as successful (you can send it certain zip codes to change that default behavior). Once in the production environment AVS is actually performed. I can tell from the response that the credit card is not a US issued card as AVS is only available for US issued credit cards (and some Canadian cards). There is no way around this.