# ReasonResponseCode:17 (authorize.net AIM transaction)

Tags: android, authorize.net

I am using AIM transaction for authorize.net, If i use visa card for production account it is working fine but it is giving error for any master card.
Master card detail:
number: 5123456789012346
cvv:100
exp:05/17

Error detail:
name: "RRC_3_17"
notes: The merchant was not configured to accept the credit card submitted in the transaction.
reason Text:The merchant does not accept this type of credit card.
Do any one have idea, how to configure authorize.net merchant account to accept master card payment?

Comment: Do not post your credentials in public.if they are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Master Card is giving AVS error for Test mode in Production account: Authorize.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449850/master-card-is-giving-avs-error-for-test-mode-in-production-account-authorize-n)